# st_asMVT in geoalchemy2

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy-2

I am new to geoalchemy/gis domain. I am looking to establish a local map server using postgis, flask and geoalchemy2. I have imported osm data into postgis and able to see it using qgis software. How can I serve mvt tiles using flask+geoalchemy2.

1. I did reflection of the existing postgis db and the tables(eg osm_roads) is available to me in python.
2. I have created ST_AsMVT aed ST_AsMVTGeom as as suggested by subclassing GenericQuery of geoalchemy2 https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spatial_functions.html#geoalchemy2.functions.GenericFunction
3. How can I recreate the query like shown in http://www.pythonexample.com/snippet/python/flask_mvtpy_giohappy_python from pure geoalchemy2 ie not resorting to raw SQL? In other words how can I replace the psycopg2 calls with geoalchemy2 calls in the _create function of the snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that uses SQLAlchemy Core and GeoAlchemy2 to generate an ST_AsMVT- and ST_AsMVTGeom-based query:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions, select, func, column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BYTEA
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from geoalchemy2.functions import GenericFunction
import mercantile


class ST_AsMVTGeom(GenericFunction):
    name = 'ST_AsMVTGeom'
    type = Geometry


class ST_AsMVT(functions.GenericFunction):
    type = BYTEA


metadata = MetaData()

arrond = Table('arrond', metadata,
               Column('gid', Integer, primary_key=True),
               Column('nom', String),
               Column('geom3857', Geometry('MultiPolygon', 3857))
               )

engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432/db', echo=True)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = mercantile.xy_bounds(8, 5, 4)

subq = select([
    func.ST_AsMVTGeom(arrond.c.geom3857,
                      func.ST_MakeBox2D(func.ST_Point(xmin, ymin),
                                        func.ST_Point(xmax, ymax))).label('geom')
    ])
subq = subq.alias('q')

q = select([func.ST_AsMVT(column('q'), 'layer', 4096, 'geom')]).select_from(subq)

conn = engine.connect()

tile = conn.scalar(q)

with open('tile.mvt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tile)
```